# What is the etymology of the word “basic” as used in current slang?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, adjectives, vocabulary, slang

For those not familiar with the term, it is used mainly by teens and 20-somethings.

The definition can be found [at Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Basic) (look at definitions 1 and 3).

Specifically, I am *not* talking about the definition of this word that is synonymous with "simple". The common slang usage of the term has been very divergent with the word "simple"; an example use case of the word would be:

> Wow, drinking a pumpkin spice latte while wearing a North Face jacket is so basic, I can't even.

Notice how the word "simple" would not make sense in the previous example; also, despite the seemingly incomplete predicate of the second clause, this example is indeed a complete sentence. The slang use of the word "basic" is also commonly conjoined in the term "basic bitch", usually referred to a "basic" girl, and the behaviors of such an individual. See also: "fuccboi".

The question is... what is the origin and etymology of this term, and how did it develop?

Specifically, how did it develop in October 2014, as seen by the peak in this chart: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=basic%20girl%2C%20fuccboi

Notice the initial peak in usage stems from October 2014, so linking to stackexchange questions that predate this peak are useless since they obviously do not address important events that happened after the event. It would be like trying to define the slang usage of the word "Inception" with only posts from before the movie "Inception" was released.

Comment: Here's a relevant previous question: [Where did the slang word “basic” come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197952/where-did-the-slang-word-basic-come-from) Let me know if the answer there is useful to you (and if it isn't, why not).

Comment: I think it evolved because "trite" was too... basic? Gonna go with my gut and say it's a passing fad. Certainly not as 'crucial' as 80's slang.

Comment: It's a broadening, from the original unmarked 'no-frills' sense to the pejorative 'humdrum, mediocre, stale, clichéd' sense. 'Common' has likewise broadened from the 'shared' sense to the disparaging 'coarse' sense; according to Etymon, this took place 700 years ago. Apparently (ie according to [Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=basic&searchmode=none)), 'basic' was originally used in 1832 in the chemical sense!?

Comment: There's always an `Up` element in any metaphor theme involving _basic_, or _base_. The base of any physical object in a 1G field is its lowest stable point, which supports the object against gravity. So it's strong, durable, and `Down`, which leaves the question of which way is `Up`. In the case of this idiom (it's new slang to me), it seems like the vertical dimension represents a superior critical position -- basically, My style is higher than yours. Someone in the penthouse looks down on those at the base.

Comment: @JohnLawler would you say it's more synonymous with "plebeian" or "common", than it is with "trite"? It's new slang to me also.

Comment: @sumelic I actually posted here because of the inadequacy of this older post; it actually predates the biggest surge in the use of the word. 

http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=basic%20girl%2C%20fuccboi

Notice the spike in October 2014. In terms of a detailed answer: what event is the etymology of this term tied to, in that month? Is there a viral video or something that creates this popular explosion?

The song "Gucci Gucci" by Kreayshawn is linked in the old post, but the  Youtube video is dated to 2011, and thus is too old of a source to be the REASON why "basic" is currently popular.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why the answer there doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Misneac: I don't know; I've never encountered it in context.